# Is it not possible to set an item to an array in __set?

Tags: php, arrays, set

```
<?php
class foo
{  
    protected $_data;

    public function __construct()
    {                
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'things':
             return $this->_data['things'];
            break;
        }                
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        switch ($name)
        {
            case 'things':
             $this->_data['things'] = $value;
            break;

        }
    }
}

$f = new foo();

$f->things[0]['Fruits'] = ["apple", "orange", "banana"];
$f->things[0]['Vegetables'] = ["carrot", "tomato", "potato"];

$f->things[1]['Fruits'] = ["grapes", "strawberry"];
$f->things[1]['Vegetables'] = ["cabbage", "radish", "lettuce"];
print_r($f);
?>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7500148/3933332

Comment: please explain question in clear

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as below:-

```
class foo
{  
    protected $_data = array();

        public function __get($name){
           // return $this->_data($name);
        }

        public function __set($name, $value){      
              $key = key($value);   
              $key1 = key($value[$key]);  
                if(isset($this->_data[$name][$key])){
                    $this->_data[$name][$key][$key1] = $value[$key][$key1];
                }else{
                    $this->_data[$name][$key] = $value[$key];
                }              

        }
}

$f = new foo();
$f->things = [0=>['Fruits'=>["apple", "orange", "banana"]]];
$f->things = [1=>['Fruits'=>["grapes", "strawberry"]]];
$f->things = [0=>['Vegetables'=>["carrot", "tomato", "potato"]]];
$f->things = [1=>['Vegetables'=>["cabbage", "radish", "lettuce"]]];
$f->things = [2=>['Fruits'=>["mango","beet"]]];
$f->things = [2=>['Vegetables'=>["beetroot","broad beans"]]];
echo '<pre>'; print_r($f);
```

**output**:-

```
foo Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [things] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Fruits] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => apple
                                    [1] => orange
                                    [2] => banana
                                )

                            [Vegetables] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => carrot
                                    [1] => tomato
                                    [2] => potato
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Fruits] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => grapes
                                    [1] => strawberry
                                )

                            [Vegetables] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => cabbage
                                    [1] => radish
                                    [2] => lettuce
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Fruits] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => mango
                                )

                            [Vegetables] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => roseflower
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: Without it how can you get your desired array?