# Dependency injection and initialization of the object

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I am quite a newbie to decent OOP and DI, thus was wondering, if the following example and its pattern of initialization of my bootstrap class, that includes dependent objects, is really alright to use, e.g.:

```
new Session(
   new Config, 
   new Database ( 
       new Config 
   ), 
   new Page ( 
       new Config 
   ), 
   new Statistics ( 
      new Database ( 
         new Config 
      ) 
   ), 
   new Notification, 
   new Filter
);
```

I believe, those which familiar with DI could say something about the piece of code above in bootstrap object?

It looks a bit bulky but is this alright? Is this the way, that we could call it *alright/correct/acceptable*?

Comment: It's "usable", but imagine doing this all the time. It would be better to look into a DI container which you configure (once) and then use to automatically resolve objects and inject dependencies (many times). Look at [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) and [Illuminate\Container](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Container/Container.html).

Comment: @Jon I am new to automatic resolvers, could you please post an answer with examples of how to use it? I think it will be useful for future readers.

Comment: Well, I would be basically copy-pasting from the documentation... I think it's better for people to go directly to the source.

Comment: @Jon, alright, thank you anyway! I will figure this out!

Comment: I must ask, why do you have page, statistics, notification and filter being passed into a session? Dependency Injection is just that, requirements for the class to function correctly. Seems to me all you really need for a session class to function is 'new Session($db, $config);'.

Comment: @NathanBishop I wouldn't pass dependencies then. `Session` class in my project in not session initializatior. Bootstrap class does init process. `Session` manages other data..

Comment: OK, had me confused for a second than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of learning an investigating on the new issue, I have finally came to the conclusion, that for my case, the best *Dependency Injection Container* would be:

[***Dice*** - minimalist Dependency Injection Container for PHP.](https://github.com/TomBZombie/Dice)

It has only one file and in order to have the code, that's from my question be initialized, all you need is:

```
(new Dice)->create('Session');
```

*Dice* DIC will take care of the rest. You can read more about *Dice* on the [Tom Butler](http://r.je/dice.html) (developer) home page.

I personally think that this is the best (shortest and easiest) way of injecting dependencies and should be inbuilt in PHP by default, and I actually wonder why it's not?

---

In order to decouple your code from the particular dependency injection container, I'd better recommend using a custom class wrapper:

```
class DIC extends Dice
  {
    function __construct( $component, array $args = array(), $callback = null, $forceNewInstance = false )
      {
          return parent::create( $component, $args, $callback = null, $forceNewInstance = false );
      }
  }
```

which will also help to shorten even more the initialization process, to something really unbelievably amazing.

Now, in order to instantiate the complicated sets of DIs, like:

```
new Session( new Config, new Database ( new Config ), new Page ( new Config ), new Statistics ( new Database ( new Config ) ), new Notification, new Filter );
```

All you have to do is:

```
new DIC('Session');
```

If you would want to pass a parameter to the constructor, you could go with:

```
new DIC('Session', array($param));
```

I don't know what others think but *I find this amazing* (at least so far, of where I am today).

**Ask you please, be kind commenting about possible drawbacks, that I could face in the future using this DIC (Dice) or this method in general!?**