# Design patterns for often used and dependent objects in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, global-variables, local-variables

I know there are patterns like the registry, singleton, etc.

Are there design patterns for handling objects which should not be globally available but only in a local area, so that I can have diffrent objects for the same role? For example if I use a singleton I have the same object in the whole programm which is not what I want.

Comment: You mean like creating instances of certain objects in distinct scopes? Besides: _"If I use a singleton"_, you're going to run into problems

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, I have diffrent objects in diffrent scopes. Where should I create them and where should I store them? And no, I won't use singleton, it just was a radical example.

Comment: Did you look at "dependency injection"?

Comment: @JimmyT.: You create instances when and where you need them, you don't _have_ to store them. If, say, Class A depends on class B, assign an instance of B to a property of A, so that, if A needs B to do something, it has an instance ready. And, as Dmitry suggested, look into Dependency Injection for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common patterns dealing with object creation are the [Gang of Four Creational Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Quoting Wikipedia:

> Creational patterns are ones that create objects for you, rather than having you instantiate objects directly. This gives your program more flexibility in deciding which objects need to be created for a given case.
>
> - [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) groups object factories that have a common theme.
> - [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) constructs complex objects by separating construction and representation.
> - [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) creates objects without specifying the exact class to create.
> - [Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) creates objects by cloning an existing object.
> - [Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323) restricts object creation for a class to only one instance.

For a general rule of thumb where to put the responsibility to create an instance, have a look at the Creator pattern in [Wikipedia's article about GRASP:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Creator)

> In general, a class B should be responsible for creating instances of class A if one, or preferably more, of the following apply:
>
> - Instances of B contain or compositely aggregate instances of A
> - Instances of B record instances of A
> - Instances of B closely use instances of A
> - Instances of B have the initializing information for instances of A and pass it on creation.

The GoF Creational Patterns complement this. For instance, if you use a Factory pattern, the Factory is likely to hold the initializing information for instances of A and will pass it on creation:

```
class BMWFactory implements CarFactory
{
    // properties, ctors and stuff …

    public function createCar($color)
    {
        return new Bmw(
            $color,
            // … more arguments
        );
    }
}
```

On the other hand, it also means that a Collection may be allowed to create new instances because B then "contains or compositely aggregate instances of A.", which would lead to something like

```
class Cars
{
    // properties, ctors and stuff …

    public function createCar($color)
    {
        return new Car(/* … */);
    }
}

$bmws = new Cars($config['bmw']);
$bmws[] = $bmws->createCar('alpine white');
```

We could argue whether it's a good idea to have your collections create objects over just storing them when the created objects have an independent lifecycle. If the As created by B have the same lifetime, it's a different thing.

Instead of having B create As, you could also [delegate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29) the creation to a Factory:

```
class Cars
{
    // properties, ctors and stuff …

    public function createCar($color)
    {
        return $this->carFactory->createNewCar(/* … */);
    }
}
$bmws = new Cars(new BmwFactory);
$bmws[] = $bmws->createCar('alpine white');
```

The reason why you should always carefully consider where to to use `new` in your code is because it introduces strong coupling from B to A. Injecting the Factory loosens that coupling, especially since we [programmed to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) instead of the concrete Class.

Strong coupling makes it difficult to mock collaborators in your unit-tests. [Quoting Miško Hevery's How to Think About the “new” Operator with Respect to Unit Testing](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/)

> But the reason why Dependency Injection is so important is that within unit-tests you want to test a small subset of your application. The requirement is that you can construct that small subset of the application independently of the whole system. If you mix application logic with graph construction (the new operator) unit-testing becomes impossible for anything but the leaf nodes in your application.

The idea of separating creation from application logic is further explained in his Google Talk, which is linked in my related answer [Dependency Hell — how does one pass dependencies to deeply nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094744/dependency-hell-how-does-one-pass-dependencies-to-deeply-nested-objects). The basic idea is to assemble everything you can reasonably assemble up-front in Factories or Builders or via a Dependency Injection Container.

### TL;DR

if you want to create objects in a local scope (because it depends on runtime information), encapsulate the Creation logic into Factories or Builders and inject these into the objects that hold the runtime information and delegate the information to the Factories and Builders from there when needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even better if we hide the fact that a factory is used?